# What could be causing the issue between my patch panel, router and switch?

Tags: router, ethernet, home-networking, switch, patch-panel

I have just wired all of my homes CAT cables into a patch panel. I have also changed the phone wall sockets into keystone Ethernet ports. Everything is wired using B configuration.

My router and modem are in the living room and the patch panel and switch are located in the garage. I plugged an Ethernet cable from the router into the wall and then another Ethernet cable from the patch panel into the switch, however the switch is not lighting up to indicate any connection. I know that the patch port running to the living room must be 9 or 10 but I have tried both to no avail. The reason I know it must be 9 or 10 is because 8/10 CAT cables are a different shade of blue and have color/color+white wires whereas the other two have color/lighter color wiring. The living room is the color/lighter color wiring.

I have tried all the patch panel ports just to be sure. I have also re punched the keystone to be A and B to see if that is the problem. What could I be doing wrong?
[image: Wired panel]
[image: The two different CAT cables]
[image: Connection into router]
[image: Connection from router into Keystone]
[image: Connection from patch panel into switch]
[image: Keystone from wall]

Clarification after comments - the cable does say *both* telephone *and* CAT5E.

[image]

Comment: Which category are those 'CAT' cables? From looking at the ends, they don't seem like *twisted*-pair cables to me (and the color scheme of the cables on "9" and "10" is a bit suspicious)...\ Did you make the blue patch cable (the one going into the router) yourself as well? Does it work when tested separately (direct from router to switch)? Can you get one of those $20 cable testers (and a pair of factory-made patch cables, to 100% rule out that as an issue) and make sure they at least get the LEDs light up? (Test all patch panel ports _just in case_ the shade isn't exactly right.)

Comment: @user1686 - I'd noticed the lack of twist too, but 1st pic says CAT5E

Comment: the cable in the first picture has the word `Telephone` printed on it

Comment: @jsotola - yup, it says that too… but like the last pic says 'Tumble Tower' not Jenga, doesn't mean that the copy doesn't have the same functionality… though it might not, if they really cheapskated on construction; like not bothering to twist it.;) I think, though, untwisted would still make it light up, if not work properly. I'm more towards poor connection for some reason.  I've added a zoom/rotate of the cable marking to the end of the question.

Comment: I did not make the blue Ethernet cable myself. I used that cable to plug straight from the router to the switch and the switch lit up to indicate a connection. All 10 CAT cables had twisted pairs that I had to untwist to punch down.

Comment: get yourself a *RJ45 Network Cable Tester*